# JWT with Quarkus

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, quarkus

I got the following jwt

```
{
 alg: "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
 typ: "JWT"
}.
{
 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "username",
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata: "data",
 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname: "Jon",
 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname: "Doe",
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: [
  "Admin",
  "Developer",
 ],
 exp: 1677257784,
 iss: "IMS.company.com"
}.
```

How do I check if the user has a specific role when making a request?

```
 @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getAllOverview")
    @RolesAllowed({"Admin"})
    public String getAllOverview() {
        return "Do Stuff";
    }
```

But this blocks every request to the endpoint.

I'm obviously pretty new to quarkus and jwt so maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Quarkus offers some guides about security and RBAC using JWT, read them before all; this question is too generic and most probably will be closed is short time

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, Quarkus relies on the `groups` claim to assign the user a role. In your JWT you don't have the `groups` claim, but the namespaced role claim: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`

It seems that you need to set this configuration property: `smallrye.jwt.path.groups`, this should point to the claim that contains the user's groups.

This should work in your case:

```yaml
smallrye.jwt.path.groups: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
```

Have a look also at this documentation page: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt It describes in detail how Quarkus works with JWTs.

Answer (score 0):

As for `Spring` or `Java Security API`, you can get the user through the `Principal` object. In the case of `Quarkus` or `Spring`, you will get it from the `SecurityContext`.

Below is the example from Quarkus [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-basic-authentication-tutorial):

> Finally, implement the /api/users/me endpoint. As you can see from the
> source code example below, we are trusting only users with the user
> role. We are also using SecurityContext to get access to the currently
> authenticated Principal, and we return the user name, all of which is
> loaded from the database.

```
package org.acme.security.jpa;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

@Path("/api/users")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed("user")
    @Path("/me")
    public String me(@Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
        return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```